# Why logstash consumes unusually high amount of cpu

Tags: logstash

I've installed logstash in Ubuntu20 and started using systemd.No further configuration.the cpu consumption is almost 100% for all 8core.

There is a thread related to this https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-thread-using-high-cpu-usage/297634
it mentions about groak patterns, but I haven't added anything so far, apart from starting it.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the downloaded package and installed via binary the the issue resolved. The package structure is different and seems to have drastic effect on cpu. Binary is perfectly fine.